# Is there a quick way to get money?

Tags: succubox

I am at the point where I have a $100 salary and I am just waiting for $100'000 to start a company. The enemy has 1.01 fuckloadillion HP and I can't do anything against it. Is there a quick way to get $ to get to the $100'000 (without cheats)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got past that point by just waiting and I found that actually actively clicking the "work" button slows down the ticker for the money gaining so get the research for the "dup glitch" and the "free crafting glitch" and don't click it anymore. A good way to pass the time at that point is crafting with a knife and a legendary hat for the 100 gold (200 with dup glitch) and buying a bunch of loot boxes DON'T BUY THE "Quantum CPU" UPGRADE AS ALL "Box Cutter Bots" WILL DISAPPEAR instead craft a bunch of them and keep buying this will get you a bunch of EXP while you wait. Good Luck. Not only that but don't buy that many loot boxes as you grind up.

Comment: Other people may have your same problem, so it's better to explain how you solved that, instead of just saying you don't need it anymore.

Comment: Yeah done that I didn't find any ways to get more money.